# extracting a number between commas excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have phone numbers in the following format

```
[' ................ ' , ' ...........' , '...........' and so on ]
```

For example,

```
['+971527851495', '+971552907803', '+971527851495']
```

What I want:

Extract all the numbers between commas by removing all the `commas` and the `opening and closing brackets`

I have tried using text to column method which removes `[` and `'` and put all the numbers in new columns but it converts the numbers into scientific numbers which i dont want.

looking for alternative

Comment: works!! ya common senses lol

Comment: You could also set the column data type to text when using the text-to-columns dialogue

Answer (score 0):

When doing text to columns, go to the next screen after the delimiters. Select each output column and format as text.
[image]